# Customize temp location for Vs 2015

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015

When I am building my code using **VS 2015 for windows desktop**, it is using my temp location:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

is there any way to change this location?

Comment: What data is stored at `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\` ?

Comment: DLL is stored in that location